# Multiplying through Addition

Tags: c++, multiplication, addition

I want to create a function that finds the product of two integers by using addition that can handle negatives and positives both.

This is the code I have so far...
getting crazy numbers as results ..I am a noob..Thank you

```
double multi(double n1, n2)
{

  double answer(0), i=0;

  do
  {
    answer += n1; i++;
  } while (i < n2);

  return answer;
}
```

Comment: What are `input1` and `input2`? Why do you have `n1` and `n2` but don't use them?

Comment: This is barely readable pseudo-code. Clean up the presentation and make the example self-contained and complete.

Comment: Are you allowed to use doubling and halving?

Comment: @neil I don't know what that is..hmwk specifies to multiply 2 integers without using multiplication but addition and its supposed to work with neg #'s

Comment: Neil is probably talking about making the loop more efficient using bit shifts, or maybe making it work with `double` values.  I think that we need to keep things simple for you and just work with the most basic approach.  You are new to programming, so we will try not to confuse you.  Anything more complicated than what you have asked should be out of bounds! =)

Answer (score 2):

You could start by using integers instead of doubles and actually pass them both as parameters....

```
int multi( int x, int y )
{
    int answer = 0;

    // stuff goes here...

    return answer;
}
```

I suspect this is homework, so I'm not going to give you code verbatim...

But consider that if one value is negative, the result will be negated relative to the answer if that same value was positive.  Effectively if you are going to add `x` and do it `y` times, then you can flip the sign of both `x` and `y` if `y` is negative.  That negates the answer and gives you a positive `y` to loop over.

An optimization would be to check which of the two values is larger, and use the smaller one as the loop variable.

---

> ..yes this is hmwk..but I'm sorry I don't understand you mean..

Imagine you have two integers `X` and `Y`.  If `Y` is positive, it's easy to see:

```
X * Y = (X + X + X + X + ...)
```

Now, what about if `Y` is negative?  I'm going to use `-Y` to denote that:

```
X * -Y = -(X * Y)
       = -(X + X + X + X + ...)
       = (-X - X - X - X - ...)
       = ((-X) + (-X) + (-X) + (-X) + ...)
```

So, if `Y` is positive I add together `Y` copies of `X`.  If `Y` is negative I add together `-Y` copies of `-X`.

If this still doesn't help, then I suggest you sit down and think about it for a while.

Comment: ..yes this is hmwk..but I'm sorry I don't understand you mean..

Comment: I have edited my answer in an attempt to clarify.

Comment: I'm going to examine this...thanks for your time in explaining it helps me a understand a bit better!